# How to use variable defined in one binary into another binary in C

Tags: c, gcc, arm

We have two cores in microcontroller. One CM0+ and another CM7. Therefore we can't build single binary (executable) output because instructions sets are different for both cores.

However, there is single structure variable which must be accessed from both cores but defined in only single binary file. Single copy of variable is required in memory because both cores writes to the same variable and use this for synchronizing and exchanging data between cores.

Example: 
Project CM0+ : dataExchange variable is available in CM0+ project C file.

```
 stc_dataexchange dataExchange;
 stc_dataexchange *dataExchangePtr = &dataExchange;
```

Project CM7: dataExchange variable is not available in this project. But we want to address it somehow.

```
 stc_dataexchange *dataexchangeptr = &dataExchange; //dataExchange is not available. Compilation will result in error.
```

dataExchnage variable is available only in Project CM0+, Project CM7 doesn't know about this. How to initialize pointer to the address of dataExchange in CM7 project? Flash memory can be accessed by both cores.

Comment: For exchanging data I would recommend a pipeline, a shared structure for data exchange seams a bit overcomplicated for this scenario. About the shared global variable for seperate binarys with _different_ instructions sets. I would try to define a region in the flash memory that serves as shared memory, but I don't think it is as easy as you would like it to be.

Comment: Add a section in your linker with the same address on both cores and put your data there.

Comment: I don't have any idea about pipeline in C. Defining a region is flash memory should work. But this shall be achieved via linker file. We provide source code as a module to our customer and then customer integrates this source code with other module. Linker file doesn't fall in our scope. So this might be complicated. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: A linker script based solution is the right way in my eyes. You could provide the exact address and structure to your curstomers, and they adjust their linker scripts themselves. -- BTW, why do you plan to use flash? Are you aware that this is commonly read-only at run-time? If you plan to exchange changing data, you should use RAM.

Comment: @thebusybee Actually here i gave just one example. We have basically two variables. Once to store configuration which is const and goes to flash and another will be to hold various status, which will be in SRAM. But yes. It seems the best option is to use linker script based solution.

Comment: you can certainly make one binary that works on both cores, build for cortex-m0 (armv6-m) and the binary will work fine on both.  From an instruction set perspective, naturally there are other core specific features which you could if-then-else in the binary.....or just make two binaries

Comment: you could certainly have a chunk of code be common that both cores use if they can share the same address spaces. and craft your linker script such that for the common code/variables they land in the same place.  short of that just the variables can be linked such that they land in the same place.  keep those globals in their own file and name the object in the linker script (in their own section definition) is a quick way to do that.

Comment: thumb2 is just an extension to thumb not a different instruction set.  the cortex-m0 has the first set of thumb2 instructions the m3 to m7 have an additional set.  but both support "all thumb variant" instructions as well as the armv6-m thumb2 extensions.